# ValueError: Theano nvcc.flags support only parameter/value pairs without space between them

Tags: gpu, theano

I tried to configure theano to use gpu in win10 in My laptop with NVIDIA Geforce 940m. I have downloaded and installed vs2012 and cuda7.5 without any error message. I use anaconda2 for python, and install theano using "pip install theano", and create a .theanorc file in my home directory. Everything seems fine. But When I import theano in anaconda prompt, the following error pops up:

> ValueError: Theano nvcc.flags support only parameter/value pairs
>   without space between them. e.g.: '--machine 64' is not supported, but
>   '--machine=64' is supported. Please add the '=' symbol. nvcc.flags
>   value is '-LC:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\libs'

But the error message does not consistently show up. There is another error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano__init__.py", line 42,
>   in 
>       from theano.configdefaults import config   File "C:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       convert=floatX_convert,),   File "C:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py", line
>   270, in AddConfigVar
>       configparam.fullname) AttributeError: ('This name is already taken', 'floatX')

For your information, I post the contents of .theanorc file:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\CUDAToolkit_7.5.{57548CFE-7018-485B-A9DD-BC53E4140915}

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
flags = -LC:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\libs
compiler_bindir = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin
```

Such error messages also occur to keras. The two packages cannot be used. But when I tried deleting the .theanorc file from my home directory, no more error! It seems there is something wrong with .theanorc or some others involved. Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete the last two sentences for [ncvv], it worked for testing theano gpu file. But in anaconda prompt, it shows:

Using gpu device 0: GeForce 940M (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN not available)

DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT mod.cu

Creating library C:/Users/YL/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_78_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.12-64/tmp6vtxlj/97496c4d3cf9a06dc4082cc141f918d2.lib and object C:/Users/YL/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_78_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.12-64/tmp6vtxlj/97496c4d3cf9a06dc4082cc141f918d2.exp